# Race condition when hooking appendChild

Tags: javascript, html, hook

I've encountered a really weird race condition when hooking appendChild.
consider this code:

```
var RealAppend = IframeWindow.Element.prototype.appendChild;
IframeWindow.Element.prototype.appendChild = function(){
    RealAppend.apply(this, arguments); //some more code here --- >};
```

I'm hooking some iframe appendchild that's why I'm doing "IframeWindow.Element.prototype.appendChild" with the IframeWindow as the iframe content window.

Now after I'm hooking the appendchild then I start to append nodes to the iframe , one of the nodes is a simple div element with id="somediv" , and another node is a javascript element and as soon as the javascript is executed it will use `document.createElement`  to create an iframe and set its attributes and than it will execute `document.getElementById('somediv').appendChild(CreatedIframe);`
which will append the created iframe to the "somediv" , my goal here is to intercept the last appendchild and hook the appendchild of that iframe also.
now a first I thought that maybe I need to actually override the appendchild like this:

```
someDiv.appendChild = function(){.....
```

but after more tests i can see that sometimes my code does succeed and hooks the last iframe and sometimes the `SomeDiv.appendChild` is the native code and my code fails.

Any ideas why?

EDIT:
I think its might related to the fact that i'm using

```
document.createRange().createContextualFragment(strHTML);
}
```

to parse html as string and then append the nodes to the iframe so maybe the div (somediv) is getting a clean appendChild from there? but why sometimes it does work and sometimes not?
one other thing is that after the page loads and i'm using dev tools to get the somediv.appendchild i'm getting the hooked code every time so the problem happens only when the javascript code executes

Answer (score 1):

So i managed to figure out what was the problem, so if anyone will ever encounter this here is the solution:
When i was parsing the html string to nodes so i can append them to the iframe i was first using the "DOMParser" API and i missed the fact that the DOMParser uses the document from the caller contentWindow so instead of calling DOMParser like this:

```
new DOMParser();
```

i needed to call it like that:

```
new HookedIframeContentWindow.DOMParser();
```